# Inheriting from generic class that also inherits from a generic singleton

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, singleton

I'm having difficulty inheriting from a generic class that is itself inherited from a generic singleton.

I am trying to make an inventory base class that is a singleton and derive different inventory types from this with different derived items.

Code has been simplified for brevity.

```
public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static bool m_ShuttingDown = false;
    private static object m_Lock = new object();
    private static T m_Instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_ShuttingDown)
                return null;
            lock (m_Lock)
            {
                if (m_Instance == null)
                {
                    m_Instance = (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));    
                    if (m_Instance == null)
                    {
                        var singletonObject = new GameObject();
                        m_Instance = singletonObject.AddComponent<T>();
                        singletonObject.name = typeof(T).ToString() + " (Singleton)";

                        DontDestroyOnLoad(singletonObject);
                    }
                }    
                return m_Instance;
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        m_ShuttingDown = true;
    }
    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        m_ShuttingDown = true;
    }
}

public class Inventory<T> : Singleton<Inventory<T>> where T : Item
{   
    ...
}
public class EquipmentInventory : Inventory<Equipment>
{
    ...
}
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Name = "Item";
}
public class Equipment : Item
{
    public string Name = "Equipment";
}
```

I can't access the Instance;

```
private EquipmentInventory equipmentInventory;
private Inventory<Item> inventory;

public void Run()
{
    var cachedInventory = Inventory<Item>.Instance;  //returns null
    var cachedEquipmentInventory = EquipmentInventory.Instance as EquipmentInventory;  //returns null
}
```

Both statements return null.

The purpose of this, is that each inventory type will be a singleton and each type of inventory will be implent different item types, so that the base inventory will use the Item type, while the Equipment inventory will be implemented using the Equipment item type.

Here is an alternate method, which seems to solve this

```
public abstract class Inventory<T, TClass> 
        : Singleton<TClass> where TClass 
        : MonoBehaviour where T : Item
    {

    }
public class EquipmentInventory : Inventory<Equipment, EquipmentInventory>
    {

    }
```

I haven't fully tested this yet with actual code, but will update when I have tested it more thoroughly

Please assist.

Comment: In the code you've provided you never assign to any of the `m_Instance` fields, so they are all null by default.

Comment: In your question's code you didn't assign to `m_Instance`, is it the same in your real code? If yes then there's your problem

Comment: This might be due to my simplification, i'll look into it.  The singleton class was taken from here http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton  I'll add the full definition.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile as there is no non-generic `Inventory` class, so `Inventory.Instance` is invalid.

Comment: `var cachedEquipmentInventory = EquipmentInventory.Instance as EquipmentInventory;` is always null because the type of `Instance` for that class is `Inventory<Equipment>` and not `EquipmentInventory` (an invalid cast results in null).

Comment: I didnt think doing " new GameObject();" worked like you thought I thought you had to instantiate it..

Comment: @Knoop - if i read it correctly, `Instance` should be of type `T`, so the `Instance` of `Inventory<Equipment>` should be of type `Equipment`. You're right of course, that it will never be `EquipmentInventory`.

Comment: @Corak No, an `Instance` of `Inventory<Equipment>` is of type `Inventory<Equipment>`. `Inventory<T>` extends `Singleton<Inventory<T>>`, so its `Instance` is of type `Inventory<T>`. The `T` in the `Singleton<T>` definition is different from the `T` in the `Inventory<T>` definition.
But obviously it still cannot ever be `EquipmentInventory`.

Comment: The code does compile.  I have tried removing where T : Item with no success.  The singleton class that I have shown, works fine for a single class, ie public class Inventory2 : Singleton<Inventory2>

Comment: @Craig Here, I removed Unity-specific stuff to show you that the line `Inventory.Instance` indeed does not compile: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DxvSVP

It's much harder to help you if you don't provide the actual code, and this clearly isn't it, since _it doesn't compile_. Maybe you have an `Inventory` type that's non-generic somewhere else and you forgot to include it?

Comment: @V0ldek - It _felt_ like i misread something. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Inventory<Item>.Instance compiles, but still returns null.  It's not necessary that I use the Inventory class directly and can be abstract if necessary.

Comment: Well, then the only thing that it leaves us with is: are you sure that `m_ShuttingDown` is false when you access the instance? If `OnApplicationQuit` or `OnDestroy` were called before the access, the null would be explained. It's probably the only rational explanation left at this point. You can use a debugger to check that.

Comment: Removing these two functions changes nothing.  the Singleton code fails when it enters the lock (m_Lock) section and m_Instance isn't being found or created, specifically, m_Instance=singletonObject.AddComponent<T>(); fails.

Comment: appologies, I'm not sure how to make comment text appear as code.

Comment: @Craig - when commenting, click on the little "help" link, which shows you to surround code with backticks (`) to make it appear as code. See also: [comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Perhaps it's not worth inheriting from the inventory class and have each contextual inventory have it's own implementation.

Comment: I just copied and tested your code and it "works" for me. The main problem is rather the console which states: `The class named 'Inventory'1' is generic. Generic MonoBehaviours are not supported!
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()` therefore it returns `null` since the `AddComponent` never succeded

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it to be Unity compatible.  I've updated the op with a potential solution.

Comment: @BugFinder yes it is actually the way to go for creating `GameObjects` from scratch (see [`GameObject` constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-ctor.html))

Comment: @derHugo odd, I remember seeing somewhere it didnt work right if you did that.. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is caused by

```
public class Inventory<T> : Singleton<Inventory<T>> : where T : Item { }
```

Here you "pass in" the generic type `Iventory<T>` into the `Singleton` even though later you explicitly inherit from that `Inventory<T>` class.

---

Here is one possible solution though it might seem like a bit strange workaround at first:

Make your Inventory take a second generic type, use the first one inside the class as needed and "forward" the second one to the `Singleton<T>` like e.g.

```
// Note how for the limitation via where you still can use the generic type
// which makes sure no other MonoBehaviour can be passed to TSelf by accident
public class Inventory<TItem, TSelf> : Singleton<TSelf> where TItem : Item where TSelf : Inventory<TItem,TSelf>
{
    public TItem reference;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!reference) reference = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TItem>();
    }
}
```

Then in the implementation your pass additionally in your own final (non-generic) type so it can be properly "forwarded" to the `Singleton<T>` like e.g.

```
public class EquipmentInventory : Inventory<Equipment, EquipmentInventory> { }
```

*Note that anyway this class has to be in a separated file called `EquipmentInventory.cs` otherwise it won't work as component in Unity.*

---

This works now since now you explicitly pass in the type `EquipmentInventory` for `TSelf` which is then forwarded to the `Signleton<T>` so the return type of `Instance` is explicitly `EquipmentInventory`.

---

In general get used to rather have one script file for each individual class/type.

Additionally I would slightly alter your fields in `Item` and `Equipment` like e.g.

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private string _name;

    public string Name => _name;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _name = GetName();
    }

    protected virtual string GetName()
    {
       return nameof(Item);
    }
}
```

and

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Equipment : Item
{
    protected override string GetName()
    {
        return nameof(Equipment);
    }
}
```

---

And this is how it looks like e.g.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public EquipmentInventory equipmentInventory;

    [ContextMenu("Run")]
    public void Run()
    {
        equipmentInventory = EquipmentInventory.Instance;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll accept this answer, you've confirmed that passing in a second parameter works nicely.  Thanks for the video, that really help.

Comment: Oh I didn't see actually that while I was writing my post you came to the same idea ^^

Comment: Yes, but you gave a good explanation, which is super helpful.